# Android :: how to quit complete application, on dialog box button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using below code to quit the application.

Case is if internet is not available then it shows the dialog box saying Internet is not available and press Ok. Once user press Ok it close the app but still app shows in Recent apps list.

Below is the code ::

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder1.setTitle("Oops! Internet not available.");
        builder1.setMessage("Connect to Internet and Restart App.");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
             intent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        startActivity(intent);
                
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();
```

After using above code, still it shows in recent app list.

I have already tried below things.

> System.exit(0);
>
> finish();
>
> intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

Please tell me how can remove the app from recent app list.

Comment: Why do you want it to disappear from recent apps?

Comment: my client want this...

Comment: reason for down vote?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are number of ways to remove the most recent app from the history list.

Via Activity Manger:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  if(am != null) {
     List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = am.getAppTasks();
     if (tasks != null) {
         tasks.get(0).finishAndRemoveTask();
     }
  }
```

Via manifesto.xml

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2" android:excludeFromRecents="true"></activity>
```

Or via intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, NewActivity.class); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: am.getAppTasks and finishAndRemoveTask are new api....i have this in manifest  android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="22"

Comment: Well there is always a chance that older versions of Android don't even support removing an app/activity from the history window.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following in your `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void finish(){

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){

        finishAndRemoveTask();

    }
    else{

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        startActivity(intent)

    }

}
```